# I cancelled SIM unlock and now I cannot unlock the device

Tags: sony-ericsson-xperia-x8, sim-unlocking

When I inserted SIM card into my phone I tapped the "cancel" button, assuming that it would be possible to unlock it later. But I fear that my assumption was wrong.

The device is a **Sony Ericsson XPERIA X8**.

Sadly I cannot find anything in "Settings" to unlock the SIM.

I have tried removing and inserting the SIM card several times, but it doesn't help. Somehow the devices remembers that I selected cancel. I'm not seeing any prompts related to unlocking the device.

---

I can see that the APNs page is empty. There is no Add button on it.

```
Settings -> Wireless & network settings -> Mobile network settings -> Access Point Names
```

---

```
Mobile network state
Disconnected
```

---

```
Firmware version
2.1-update1
```

---

```
Build number
2.0.1.A.0.47
```

---

```
Model number
E15i
```

---

Is it hidden in another app or is there something I have overlooked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally solved it.. I have found this ansewer by yy502 on [cyanogenmod](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/7805-unlock-sim-with-pin-after-entering-the-android-os/)

```
1) you've missed the PIN prompt when phone starts up. no phone calls.
2) go to "location & security settings"
3) go to "set up SIM card lock"
4) un-tick "Lock SIM card"
5) enter your PIN as required
6) your phone will now connect to the mobile network. full bars!!
7) re-tick "set up SIM card lock" if you still want to protect your phone using SIM card PIN
8) enter your PIN as required
```